# the eclipse executable was unable to find its shared library

Tags: nautilus, eclipse

I have the problem as

"the eclipse executable was unable to find its shared library"

when I open eclipse. The other thing is when i open it with nautilus command like, I type sudo nautilus and i navigate to the folder where eclipse is located. it is working fine. it will open properly. what is the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of googling and found that this seems to be a common issue within the `eclipse.ini` file.

Open `/etc/eclipse.ini` up in a text editor and check the following:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.0.100.v20080509-1800.jar

--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
```

Make sure what is stated here matches the actual filenames exactly.

For more info see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17824433/how-to-fix-the-eclipse-executable-launcher-was-unable-to-locate-its-companion-sh) and [here](http://codewithgeeks.blogspot.co.uk/2013/11/fixing-eclipse-executable-launcher-was.html).

Hope this helps/